# What do the dots mean in DABCO's IUPAC name?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I came across [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DABCO) molecule with the following IUPAC name: 1,4-Diazabicyclo[2.2.2]octane

What do the dots inside the brackets mean, or where can I read about the IUPAC guidelines that require this?

Comment: Better question is what the numbers they separate mean...

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37970/what-does-the-h-k-and-5-2-2-02-6-mean-in-dibenzoh-k-4-oxatricyclo5-2 https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27217/how-to-rationalise-the-iupac-name-for-tetrahedrane

Answer (score 1):

The dots are used in bicyclic compounds and indicate the number of carbons in each bridge.  DABCO has three bridges, each with two carbons.